# How do I make my `TextArea` content visible HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML page where I am fetching data from a text file and displaying it in a `TextArea`. The data is being sent through as expected, but it is not displaying in a visible format

If you click and drag your mouse in the `TextArea`, as if you were highlighting/selecting the content, then it is visible, but not on it's own.

Issue: This is what I am able to see

[image: this is what i am able to see] 
But when I select some text by clicking and dragging, I am able to see this:
[image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2w89.png)
**code:**

This is the function I am using

```
function rdata() {
  var file = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var textArea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
    textArea.value = e.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="backdrop">
        <div class="colors">
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea id="myTextArea" onclick="rdata();"></textarea>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**CSS code**

```
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}


input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container, .backdrop, #myTextArea {
  font: 12px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 48%;
  height: 250px;
}

#myTextArea {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  color: transparent;
  resize: none;
}

.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.colors {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

i have changed the color to black for #myTextArea it is working but my text appears "Blur" how do i fix it

[output appears blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zERDl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
change color in your CSS

 #myTextArea {
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 0;
   background-color: transparent;
   z-index: 2;
   color: red;  /* i change it to red , u can change to any color u want */
   resize: none;
 }
```

Comment: can you can tell me how do i fix the text which is coming blur question updated please help out

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `color: transparent;` line in the CSS for `#myTextArea`. That causes the text to be transparent. Remove it or change it to an actual visible color.

Comment: can you can tell me how do i fix the text which is coming blur question updated please help out

Comment: Probably some other issue going on with your odd CSS. Why is it like that anyway? I would recommend getting rid of most of it, as it doesn't seem to serve any functional design purpose and is causing problems for you.